# How to ignore non-existent paths In Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a way to read a bunch of files from S3, but there is a potential for a path to not exist. I would just like to ignore the fact that the path does not exist, and process all information possible.  Example I want to read in files:

```
files_to_read = []
for id in ids_to_process:
    for date in dates_to_process:
        files_to_read.append('s3://bucket/date=' + date + '/id=' + id + '/*.parquet')
sqlContext.read.parquet(*files_to_read)
```

The issue is that some id's may not have started until a certain date, an while I can figure that out, it's not very easy to do it programmatically.  What would the easiest way be to either a) ignore a file if the path does not exist. b) check if a path exists.

I have tried `sqlContext.sql("spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles=true")`, which does not seem to work.  Would there be any similar option that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here, missing file really means **the deleted file under directory after you construct the DataFrame**.

It is recommended to judge whether the target file exists in python in advance instead of handing it over to spark.

Comment: So the only option for an actual missing file is to use something like boto to check if the path exists?

Comment: In my limited experience with spark, no related parameters in spark have been found yet. You can try to use ```os.path``` library of python to determine whether the file exists. But I am not sure if it supports the s3 file system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, maybe looking to catch the specific exception that is being thrown when a file does not exist (I believe in Scala it's an AnalysisException):

```
df = None
for path in paths_to_read:
    try:
        temp_df = sqlContext \
            .read \
            .parquet(path)

        if df is None:
            df = temp_df
        else:
            df = df.union(temp_df)
    except:
        # Ignoring this path
        # print("Path " + path + " cannot be read. Ignoring.")
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen something in pyspark that can do that. I also faced this and this is what I did:

Have a list of S3 addresses that you want to read.

```
addrs = ["s3a://abc", "s3a://xyz", ... ]
```

Test the links beforehand, and remove them if not accessible

```
for add in addrs:
    try:
        spark.read.format("parquet").load(add)
    except:
        print(add)
        addrs.remove(add)
```

Read the updated list using spark

```
sdf_a = spark\
        .read\
        .format("parquet")\
        .load(addrs)
```